# MySQL 8 SELECT statement syntax issue after upgrading from 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have recently started to test MySQL 8 instead of 5.7

Basic SQL select statements fail, that worked correctly in 5.7 and earlier. One such example is:

`select * from member;`

*You have an error in your SQL syntax.... see the manual for usage near 'member'.*

However, the statement runs fine if you enclose the name of the table you are querying, in this case member, with backticks OR if you prefix the database name to that of the table name, separated with a period.

`` select * from `member` `` as well as `select * from mydbname.member` works just fine.

What I want to know is:

1. Is there a sql-mode value, or config file setting one can activate/deactivate this behavior?
2. The mysql online reference examples for SELECT and JOIN syntax is also plain identifiers, such as `SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4) ON (t2.a = t1.a AND t3.b = t1.b AND t4.c = t1.c)`. Notice t1 is not enclosed in backticks and the database is also not prefixed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose `member` is a keyword in MySQL 8. But need to check))

Comment: Yes, I have just discovered it as well. WHYYYYY

Comment: Seems a new operator for JSON called [`MEMBER OF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) was added to MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks when your database object names are the same as certain reserved keywords in MySQL.

In your case, `member` is actually a reserved-word in MySQL since version 8.0.17:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

> Is there a sql-mode value, or config file setting one can activate/deactivate this behavior?

Unlike Microsoft SQL Server's "compatibility level" option, which changes the set of reserved words in queries, MySQL's compatibility options list does not let you restrict reserved-words: https://makandracards.com/makandra/51169-understanding-sql-compatibility-modes-in-mysql-and-mariadb - and I strongly recommend against using any of MySQL's compatibility modes because you **really, really** don't want MySQL 4.x or MySQL 5.x's non-standard behaviour (like `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY = off`).